# Is it safe to store passwords in powershell's $env variable?

Tags: security, powershell

I have a few scripts in my $profile that require passwords for things like connecting to a corporate VPN or sending a command to a virtualized VM.

I don't want to type these passwords over and over and storing the passwords in my $profile is insecure. So I've come up with a solution. On $profile startup, I do something like this

```
$env:VpnPassword =  (Get-Credential Domain\George.Mauer).GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

So when powershell starts I enter a password one time and in any scripts I can then use `$env:VpnPassword`.

I've confirmed that the variable is available only to the PS Session. And my reasoning is, since it seems to be in memory, that's a reasonably safe place to store it.

Is my logic sound? *Are* the `$env` values I'm creating stored only in memory? What about the pagefile? Is that something that could be used to somehow grab these strings? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do without introducing whole new systems?

Comment: Well store passwords in plain text is anyway not safe. You can use ``Import-Credential`` and ``Export-Credential`` from ``bsonposh`` module or at least store them as ``SecureString``.

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev what security threat can be posed by storing passwords in memory? That should be silo'ed by the OS, right? If they bypass application memory space isolation there's probably all sorts of issues to worry about. I could store it as SecureString but I'm not sure what sort of attack that would protect me from. I'll look at `bsonposh` but I'm not sure I like the idea of adding another dependency.

Comment: Registry I guess..  Of course it depends on your environment. But if you run to this question, then I think you should somehow protect yourself, wouldn't it be better? Store passwords as ``SecureString`` not that hard.

Comment: Well yes, but I want to understand how this stuff works as well and why we do certain things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I verified $env is ONLY in ram. It left no pointers when PS closed. the underlying destructor fires even if you punch the PS exe into breaking, it still cleans up. Even with a shared memory attack, that address space is only available to system32, etc and kernel mode drivers as far as I know. You would have to know the exact memory address and size of the data to find anything assuming you even had a process that was elevated enough. That being said, I dont really see any need for encryption.

This answer will begin the self destruct sequence on WM_CLOSE...