# Is it dangerous to store a password in a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, passwords, password-encryption

I'm writing a GUI program with PyQt5 which takes the user's password for entering the app, I need to store the entered password in the memory for further processing, is it dangerous? 
I found this thread:

[Is it safe to store passwords in powershell's $env variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504850/is-it-safe-to-store-passwords-in-powershells-env-variable)

Based on the above link, it's OK, but I'm still in doubt.
Or if storing plain text password in the memory is dangerous, encrypting and saving it in a variable could be a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with storing a plain text password in a memory variable. It is quite common and would be normal for an application to decrypt a secure password and store it in memory.

Answer (score 1):

While using the environment variable is fine and it is common approach to store sensitive data but if you want to go further deeper in achieving the security of your secrets (password, API keys etc), then you should opt for [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) which provides more secure mechanisms to store sensitive information on the server rather then keeping them in clear text.